# Pulling reddit comments using python PRAW and creating a dataframe with the results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reddit, praw

I'm looking to pull all the comments from a reddit post and ultimately get the author name, comment, and upvotes into a dataframe. I'm fairly new to programming so I'm having a tough time..

Right now I'm pulling the stickied comment using PRAW and trying to use a for loop to iterate through the comments and create a list of dictionaries with the author and comment. For some reason it's only adding the first author comment dictinoary pairing to the list and repeating it. Here's what I have:

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import pprint

reddit = praw.Reddit(xxx)
sub = reddit.subreddit('ethtrader')
hot_python = sub.hot(limit=1)



for submissions in hot_python:
    if submission.stickied:
        print('Title: {}, ups: {}, downs: {}'.format(submissions.title, submissions.ups,submissions.downs))
        post = {}
        postlist = []                                                 
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
        for comment in submission.comments: 
            post['Author'] = comment.author
            post['Comment'] = comment.body
            postlist.append(post)
```

Any ideas? Apologies for the ugly code I'm a novice here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for submissions in hot_python:
    if submission.stickied:
        print('Title: {}, ups: {}, downs: {}'.format(submissions.title, submissions.ups,submissions.downs))
        postlist = []                                                 
        submission.comments.replace_more(limit=0)
        for comment in submission.comments: 
            post = {} # put this here
            post['Author'] = comment.author
            post['Comment'] = comment.body
            postlist.append(post)
```

You should declare a new `post` dict inside the `for` loop, because when you append it to the list, you're actually appending a reference to the `post` dict, and then you change the same dict with the new data and it changes for all references to that dict. Your list at the end is just a list of references to the same dict.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Simple fix bit makes sense now. Appreciate it :D